# How can I extend stl classes to have my own methods?

Tags: c++, stl

I know that it is a **bad** idea to inherit from stl classes.  But is there any other way to extend them?

Let's say that to improve readability, I wanted to be able to call an "add" method on my vectors instead of the less readable "push_back".

Or perhaps I want to add a simple hasKey method to my std::map.

Is there any way that I could do that, aside from creating an entire wrapper class with a std::vector as a member, passing each function call from my wrapper to the vector?

Comment: *'instead of the less readable "push_back"."* .... what?

Comment: myVector.add(myThing) is, in my opinion, easier to quickly read than myVector.push_back(myThing).

Comment: Every C++ programmer should know `std::vector::push_back` while they would need to learn what `add` does. But let's pretend it is just a (bad) example.

Comment: Where does `add` put the item?  What are you going to name `push_front`?  How about `insert`?

Comment: @CrazyEddie: This has tons of issues. I would naively assume `add` to be some 90s `operator+`

Comment: It's not a question of knowing what it does.  It's a question of readability.

Another example would be using `myMap.hasKey(key)` instead of `myMap.find( key ) != myMap.end()`  That one is clearly easier to quickly grok.

Comment: @user1916754: This is a horrible example. Every C++ programmers knows the standard library and so should you. Do you also `#define begin {` and `#define end }`?

Comment: @user - but `find` does something totally different than I'd expect from `hasKey`.  The authors of `map` (and the associative container concept in general) did a good thing by not polluting the interface with every conceivable operation.  Discovering whether a key is in the map is as easy as you show and would require a `find` anyway even if it was implemented in `map` itself.  You have much to learn about software design and maintenance.

Comment: One should always define better names where possible. Any competent C++ programmer can easily check what it's defined as — this is a core skill in reading C++ headers, where typedefs are one of the favourite tricks. However, instead of `hasKey(..)`, one would simply use `!myMap.count(key)`, which does the same, so the STL is only slightly less readable than would be perfect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use free functions:

```
template<typename... Args>
bool has_key(std::map<Args...> const& map, typename std::map<Args...>::key_type key) {
  return map.find(key) != map.end();
}
```

Don't use inheritance if it's not necesarry. That's silly.

Comment: +1. It also plays very nicely with Scott Meyer's observation on [non-member functions and encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Answer (score 3):

Once developers become accustomed to the STL names of things, having changed them will make the code less maintainable.  This is generally a bad idea.  In practice, since STL classes don't provide a virtual destructor, it's not possible to inherit from them and have good destruction behavior.